# Add link to Sales Order on Sales Order Detail form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Sales Order Detail is obviously related to Sales Order as N:1. It even has `salesorderid` field. But this field is displayed neither on form editor nor on view editor.

Do I have to write custom code to display link to Sales Order on Sales Order Detail form and view? Or is there some common-known hack to do it?

Comment: So it doesn't show up as an available field to choose from when you customize the form?

Comment: @Daryl, no it does not. Not on form editor not in view editor.

Comment: skfd, why do you need to have this link on the sales order detail? I've always accessed sales order details from the context of their parent order. Just curious, I agree with your assessment, it is an artifical block imposed by CRM for some (as far as I can tell undocumented) reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this but if you are looking for ideas have you tried directly editting the FormXML in the customization.xml file? (http://crmblog.sentri.com/2011/05/importing-customizations-in-crm-2011.html)

In customizations.xml change the entity formXML. A typical form control lives in a tab -> section -> row -> cell, like customer on incident for example:

```
<row>
                          <cell auto="false" showlabel="true" locklevel="0" rowspan="1" colspan="2" id="{82172fc9-a003-4203-87e6-73c8808ae942}" labelid="{bbfe38a0-67e7-4854-9bfd-1a861e5bac76}">
                            <labels>
                              <label description="Customer" languagecode="1033" />
                            </labels>
                            <control id="customerid" classid="{270BD3DB-D9AF-4782-9025-509E298DEC0A}" datafieldname="customerid" disabled="false">
                              <parameters>
                                <AutoResolve>true</AutoResolve>
                                <DisableMru>false</DisableMru>
                              </parameters>
                            </control>
                          </cell>
                        </row>
```

You could try to generate a new guid for the cell and label, give the control a uniqueId and make datafieldname="salesorderid"

it would syntactically correct, but I'd be wary if they block it at design time there might be a reason. Good luck.